# Hibernate Validation Framework not able to load javax PersistenceProvider

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, classloader, tomcat8, bean-validation

I am using SpringBoot version 2.1.2.RELEASE. As part of spring-boot-starter-web I got hibernate-validator:6.0.14.Final on my classpath. Also I have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

I am using Validator to validate input data to a Service. After the data is validated and processed I user JPA repository to persist the data to DB.

The application is deployed on a Tomcat server as a war. When I run the application I get following Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:111) ~[javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:2.2]
at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Persistence.java:141) ~[javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:2.2]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:52) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingJPATraversableResolverForSingleValidation.lambda$isReachable$0(CachingJPATraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:43) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingJPATraversableResolverForSingleValidation$$Lambda$849/1933850918.apply(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1118) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingJPATraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingJPATraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:43) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1285) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:527) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:496) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:430) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:6.0.14.Final]
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:330) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at com.billing.service.BenefitServiceImpl.saveBenefitRequest(BenefitServiceImpl.java:51) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.billing.controller.BillingController.submitEvent(BillingController.java:41) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:185) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:539) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.33]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_40]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.33]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
... 98 more
```

Looks like its not able to find the PersistenceProvider.

I tried following things:

1. If I disable the validator, the persistence to the DB works fine. That mean its only the validations not working.
2. I checked the tomcat class loading logs. I see following:

   [Loaded javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider from file:/app/tomcatprofile/webapps/billing-service/WEB-INF/lib/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar]

Also, checking on web for the error I found that javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is deprecated. Don't know how its being referred by validation framework.

Another thing I tried today, If I put the javax.persistence-api.jar in tomcat lib directory, it starts working fine.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation. As I understood there is no need to add the validator as dependency. Just add validation rules to your model and the @Valid annotation in controller method together with a custom exception handler will do the job for you.

Comment: I do not want to run validations in the Controller as the requirement is to save the incoming request as-is before running validation. If I add @Valid in the Controller itself, I will not be able to capture invalid request.

Comment: Okay, then do not add the annotation and trigger validation on your own. The needed beans should be registered and should be available per dependency injection I think. also you have the possibility to look at that annotation and how spring is using it and implement the validation as you want.